# Utilizar @keyframes do css com o angular 5.2.6

Tags: css, angular, animação, component

Estou migrando um projeto e o mesmo possuía algumas animações. O mesmo há animações no css com @keyframes, mas ao colocar diretamente no css do componente e visualizar a página gerada do angular não funciona. Dei uma olhada na parte de animações https://angular.io/guide/animations mas, entendi pouco. 
Esse é um código de exemplo que estou tentando migrar para o angular.

```css
p{
text-align:center;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

@keyframes pular {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  40% { transform: scale(1.10); }
  50% { transform: scale(1); }
  60% { transform: scale(1.10); }
  70% { transform: scale(1); }
}

.pulso {
  animation-name: pular;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<p class="pulso"> teste <P>
```

`

Comment: Não entendo o seu problema! Veja funcionando em [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjkcfv).

Comment: Estranho o componente não está rodando no projeto original. Vou postar parte do código amanhã assim que chegar no trabalho

Comment: Testei e realmente o texto funciona. Agora se utiliza em um componente de ícone não consegue fazer. No projeto original funciona agora no angular não faz. Criei um novo component de exemplo com o texto e o ícone e não funcionou.  Esse é o código  Realmente funciona mas, não para o ícone. Criei um novo módulo e funcionou. Mas aí, resolvi utilizar para o ícone igual estava no projeto e não funcionou.   <p class="pulso">
  keyframes works!
</p>
<span class="mbri-desktop pulso"></span>   Estou usando o mobiriseicons

Comment: Testei com outra biblioteca foundation icons e mesmo depois de renderizada a tag <i> não permite manipulação com a propriedade transform. Mas isso apenas no angular. Sei lá o motivo.

Comment: Fiz até no component a animação e com imagem funciona até usando o keyframe para os estados mas, na tag <span>(mobiriseicons) ou <i>(foundationicons) sequer sofre alteração.

Comment: Porque não coloca dentro da tag `p` ? `<p class="pulso"> <i class="fi-book"></i> teste <p>` pode ver funcionando no [stackblitz](https://angular-xjkcfv.stackblitz.io).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica. Agradeço pela ajuda. Realmente irá resolver. Mais uma vez obrigado wmsouza